# Fastest way to check if each row contains some value in dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, isnull

I have a dataframe with around 300000 rows and 600 columns. I want to remove all rows which contain a sting "NULL" in at-least one of the columns. How would I achieve it without using for loops for rows and columns?

Will datatables work faster than normal dataframe in such case?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: You should probably define `"NULL"` as `na.strings` when importing the data. Then you could use R's facilities to handle `NA` cases, e.g., use `na.omit` or `complete.cases`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` (should be fast)

```
df1[!rowSums(df1=='NULL'),]
```

Or another option is `any` with `apply`

```
df1[!apply(df1=='NULL', 1, any),]
```

---

If we need a `data.table` solution,

```
setDT(df1)[df1[,!Reduce(`+` , lapply(.SD, `==`, 'NULL'))]]
```

If we are reading the `NULL` elements as `NA` using `na.strings='NULL' in the`read.table/read.csv` (as mentioned by @Roland)

```
 setDT(df1)[df1[, !Reduce(`+`,lapply(.SD, is.na))]]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(V1= sample(c(LETTERS[1:3],'NULL'), 20, replace=TRUE), 
        V2= sample(c(LETTERS[1:5], 'NULL'), 20, replace=TRUE),
       V3= sample(c(LETTERS[1:8], 'NULL'), 20, replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use complete.cases if you read in the data with the option na.strings = c("NA", "NULL")

```
df_complete <- df[complete.cases(df),]
```

Returns only those rows which do not contain any NA values.

Comment: This might have unintended/unwanted behaviour if there are actually NA-values OP wants to keep in the data.